# Trouble with infinite loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple shotgun game where the user vs the CPU and the both pick shot, shield or reload using enumeration but When I go to run my code it just keeps looping what the user and computer picked. I am not sure as to how to fix this

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
//Declare Variables
        Console.Title = "Welcome To The Shotgune Game";
        int CPUBullets = 3, userBullets = 3;
        ShotgunOption UserOption;
        int  userScore = 0;
        bool QUIT = false;
        double gameCount = 0.0;
        Random computer = new Random();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("SHOOT RELOAD SHIELD");

        UserOption = GetOptionFromUser();
        ShotgunOption CPUOption = (ShotgunOption)computer.Next(1, 3); // 1 is Shot, 2 is Reload, 3 is Shield

         do
        {


           // if (UserOption == "QUIT")
            //{
                //break;
            //}

            do
            {
            //Console.Write("Please enter choice, or enter QUIT to quit: ");




              switch (UserOption)
            {
                 case ShotgunOption.Shoot:
                    if((int)CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. It was a tie!", UserOption);
                        ; userBullets --;CPUBullets --; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", UserOption);
                        ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", UserOption);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    break;
                 case ShotgunOption.Reload:
                    if((int)CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. You lose!", UserOption);
                         ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You Both Gain A bullet", UserOption);
                        userBullets++; CPUBullets++; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", UserOption);

                    }
                    break;
                  case ShotgunOption.Shield:
                    if((int)CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. You lose!", UserOption);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", UserOption);
                        ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", UserOption);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    break;                  

            }
          }
            while (UserOption != ShotgunOption.Shield || CPUOption != ShotgunOption.Shield);
        } while (QUIT == false || gameCount != 3 || UserOption != ShotgunOption.Shield || CPUOption != ShotgunOption.Shield);



        if (gameCount > 1)
        {
            DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption,  userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
        }
```

Comment: You prompted for input **OUTSIDE** of your loops, then never prompt for input inside the loops. Therefore whatever was chosen at the beginning become PERMANENT choices.

Comment: Usually this kind of problems are solved very quickly using the debugger. You should try it. Soon, you will ask yourself how it was possible to program without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never updating the user's input within your loop. Once the user makes a choice, it is never changed.
`UserOption = GetOptionFromUser();` should also occur in your loop. At least that's what I can tell from a quick glance.

Comment: Also, along with my answer I should ask: why use a do/while instead of a regular while? If the user wants to quit before the first round, do you force them to play the first round?